# Access Token JWT validation

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt

Is it really required to validate the access token by decrypting it using the public key? I am asking this question related to the Azure AD. I am understanding that the JWT token can be validated to make sure it was in deed signed by Azure AD. If this is the case, are there any Azure AD endpoints where I can pass the token and get a response whether it was signed by it? All the articles over the internet explains the manual way of grabbing the public key from Azure AD endpoint and then do the decrypt steps by ourselves. Are there any automated way to validate the access tokens?

It would be great if someone can throw light on whether its a standard practice for the APIs to validate the access tokens before servicing the request.

Comment: Azure AD does not provide endpoint to validate token. You need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is considered best security for APIs to validate JWT access tokens on every request. This approach is fast and scales to a microservices architecture, where Service A can forward the access token to Service B and so on.

The result can be termed a 'zero trust architecture', since both calls from internet clients and clients running within the back end involve digital verification before the API logic runs.

You are right that a certain amount of plumbing code is needed to verify JWTs. This is typically coded once in a filter and then you don't need to revisit it. For some examples in various technologies, see the [Curity API Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/api/).

I can confirm that this approach works fine for Azure AD - please post back if you run into any specific problems.

Some Authorization Servers also support token validation via [OAuth Introspection](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662), but Azure AD does not support this currently.

Introspection is most commonly used with opaque access tokens (also unsupported by Azure). See the [Phantom Token Approach](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) for further details on this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should validate it every time. The reason to use JWT is to authorize request. If you don't care who sent the request and it doesn't matter if it was a hacker or your customer than don't use jwt and oauth. If you do care and use it you have to be sure that the jwt was not changed by some hacker, so signature has to be checked.